# C# SQL update one of two joined tables

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have joined two tables (Bought and ASXCode) together in the following select statement :

```
findCommand = new SqlCommand("Select   Bought.Stockid, Bought.Buyid, Bought.BuyDate, Bought.Number_Bought," +
  " Bought.Price, Bought.Brokerage, Bought.Number_Bought,  Bought.Interest_Rate, Bought.Acc_Interest, " +
  "Bought.Total_Cost, Bought.BuyNotes, ASXCode.Stock_Code" +
  " FROM Bought  INNER JOIN ASXCode ON Bought.Stockid = ASXCode.Stockid "  +
  " ORDER BY ASXCode.Stock_Code", JKPLConnection);
```

Then I have the following code to bind the findTable to various text boxes:

```
  findAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        findAdapter.SelectCommand = findCommand;
        findTable = new DataTable();
        findAdapter.Fill(findTable);
        txtBuyId.DataBindings.Add("Text", findTable, "Buyid");
        cboS.DataBindings.Add("Text", findTable, "Stock_Code");
        dateTimePicker4.DataBindings.Add("Text", findTable, "BuyDate");
        txtDateS.DataBindings.Add("Text", findTable, "BuyDate");
        txtNumBuyS.DataBindings.Add("Text", findTable, "Number_Bought");
        txtPriceS.DataBindings.Add("Text", findTable, "Price");
        txtBrokerageS.DataBindings.Add("Text", findTable, "Brokerage");
        txtRateS.DataBindings.Add("Text", findTable, "Interest_Rate");
        txtOpInterestS.DataBindings.Add("Text", findTable, "Acc_Interest");
        txtTotalCostS.DataBindings.Add("Text", findTable, "Total_Cost");
        findManager = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[findTable];
```

I have then been able to edit, delete and add new records to the findTable.

What I want to do when the various changes have been made to the findTable, is to update the Bought table of the database with the changes.  I cannot use SqlCommandBuilder because "Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables".

From various searches I have made I understand that I need to write my own update statement to update the Bought table.  However, I am at a loss as to how to write this statement.  I am hoping someone can show me how I can do this, please.

Comment: See following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx.  Only uses the Update command and not the other lines.  The Update command must have a where statement uniquely specifying the row that need to be changed.  Usually you use the Primary Index in the where statement.

Comment: You don't  need a join for the update.  You need a separate update  for each database table, but can be combined into one command.

Answer (score 1):

Updates are simple.

```
 UPDATE <tablename> 
   SET <fieldname> = <new value>
 WHERE <filterconditon>
```

So for example

```
UPDATE users
  SET name = 'Hogan'
WHERE id = 4523
```

(if the id of my record was 4523)

In your case I expect you will be using the boughtid since the stocks data typically would not be editable.

---

Reply to comment below.

First of all you have to be careful of terms here, a table in a SQL DB is not the same as a table in HTML.

I think you are "confused" because this is not a simple operation.  You can't use a "changeBuilder" what ever that is and do it on step -- you have to do it yourself.  You have to do it for each value you want to change -- for example the update string to change the price would look like:

```
"UPDATE Bought
  SET Price = {newprice}"
 WHERE Buyid = {buyID}"
```

Passing textPriceS and BuyID as parameters.

You will have send this sql to the server.  This is just an example of what you want based on the code you show you will need to expand to include all the fields that get edited.

Comment: I am sorry that I don't get this.  I don't want to update an individual record in the Bought table of the database, I want to update (in bulk) all the changes that I have made to the findTable  following its creation - additions, deletions and edits.  I can cycle through the records in the  findTable and see all the changes I have made, but, once I close the program, all those changes are lost since the changed findTable is not updated back to the database.

Comment: @Johnkg - see my update.  Sad news, you have to update an individual record in the bought table -- there is no other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can't do it that way. but you can create a [VIEW](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) with the query you posted, and then create an [INSTEAD OF TRIGGER](http://michaeljswart.com/2012/10/triggers-on-views-what-for/) on that view. that trigger can insert/update the values to the correct tables with a logic you can define.

**UPDATE**:
Since you are joining another table to display just one column. you can also make have that column as computed column on your Bought table, that will save you the join and the VIEW/TRIGGER work and will enable you to work directly on that table in the way your code works now. I haven't tested that code, so it may not work out of the box, but it should give you a general direction:

```
ALTER TABLE Bought
ADD Stock_Code AS (SELECT TOP 1  Stock_Code FROM ASXCode AS SX WHERE SX.Stockid = Stockid)
```

However, note that if your table is large enough, this computed column can really cause severe performance impact, and it is much better to use a join.

Comment: Many thanks for your clarification I will have to rethink this all over again. When selecting from one table I used the following code to update all changes in bulk and I was trying to do emulate what this did.   'SqlCommandBuilder BoughtAdapterCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(BoughtAdapter);'
            BoughtAdapter.Update(BoughtTable);>

Comment: It is only natural you face problems here. integrating between object model and a database model will usually create some design problems. an ORM will do all of that for you, but will create other problems. eventfully you will use an ORM for the majority of your data-object work, but it is important to know SQL good enough, so you can cover the area where an ORM won't be good enough. and please mark my post as an answer if it helped you, so I get some internet gold :)